# What was Princeton 6 in Jamaican English?

Tags: slang, dialects, poetry, music

I got an Old Raggae album and started listening to "Bam Bam" by Sister Nancy ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXnT3LFTc-s))

After listening several times, I could start making out the English words ([lyrics](http://www.lyricsmania.com/bam_bam_lyrics_sister_nancy.html)):

> A me seh one thing Nancy cyaan understan 
>   one thing Nancy cyaan understan 
>   wha' mek dem a talk 'bout me ambishan
>   seh, wha' mek dem a talk 'bout me

Sure enough

> One thing Nancy can't understand (2×) 
>   What makes them talk about my ambition? (2×)

So far so good, but I am stuck on the following sentence:

> Me born an me grow in a **Princeton 6**

I tried looking up the [Parishes of Jamaica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaica#Parishes), there is no town called Princeton.  So I am not sure what it could mean here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because (I think) it's about the brand/model name of a caravan/mobile home.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I hope this is OK.  This is about **etymology** and **dialect** - granted it is a brand name.  http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: [Sister Nancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sister_Nancy), “real name Ophlin Russell-Myers, [born] 1962 ... in Kingston, Jamaica ... one of 15 siblings... [now lives] in New Jersey, where she works as an accountant at a bank”, says wikipedia, quoting partly from [jamaicaobserver.com](http://www.jamaicaobserver.com/entertainment/Nancy-s-b-day-fest-for-Queens_15712559).  Maybe you can email her via jamaicaobserver and ask the meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Since *ina* in Jamaican patois can mean simply *in* (as in Max Romeo & the Upsetters' song and album "War ina Babylon"), it seems reasonable to read the phrase "Me born an me grow in a Princeton 6" as meaning "I was born and grew up in Princeton 6." Unfortunately, the Internet appears never to have heard of the phrase "Princeton 6."

What the Internet has heard of, however, is "Kingston 6"—which happens to be a postal zone that serves the area of Liguanea in Kingston, Jamaica. In fact the entire city of Kingston is subdivided into 20 postal zones numbered 1 through 20, which would make "Kingston ##" a simple way to identify neighborhoods—not just for letter carriers, but for the people who live in each zone. (See the "Postal Service" subsection of [Wikipedia's article on Kingston, Jamaica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingston,_Jamaica).)

And in view of jwpat's finding (reported in a comment above) that Sister Nancy (Ophlin Russell-Myers) was born in Kingston, Jamaica, it seems highly likely to me that the actual phrase used in the lyrics—notwithstanding the insistence of multiple music lyrics sites that the final two words of the phrase are "Princeton 6"—is "Me born an me grow ina Kingston 6." It would be easy enough to mishear a word pronounced "Keenston" as *Princeton*.

That is a great song, by the way. I had never heard of Sister Nancy before.

Comment: I've listened to it a number of times and it really doesn't sound like "Kingston". There's a 'p' or a 'b' or something similar at the start. 1:21 in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXnT3LFTc-s

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by listening to live versions of the song—for example, [this version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KILNDJdj0s) recorded in the Hamptons—in which she more clearly says "Kingston 6" (at roughly 1:16–1:20 in this recording).

Comment: +1 for the sensible idea of listening to live versions of "Bam Bam" in hopes of hearing the singer enunciate "Kingston" more clearly. I'm not sure that the version that I linked to in your answer does the job—but it sounds like "Kingston" to me. If you have a better live version to link to, please add that link in place of the one I chose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it's [a six-berth Princeton caravan](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=princeton+6+caravan&biw=1135&bih=865&tbm=isch&imgil=NZj8GQ9bvcZ6HM%253A%253BEYknVe4QNOjtJM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.tradingpost.com.au%25252FCaravans%25252FCaravans-%25252FCARAVANS-FOR-SALE-SUNSHINE-COAST-FRANKLIN-PRINCETON-TANDEM-186%25252FNambour%25252FQLD%25252FAdNumber%2525253DD1105202392232&source=iu&pf=m&fir=NZj8GQ9bvcZ6HM%253A%252CEYknVe4QNOjtJM%252C_&usg=__K2h_VHmX_fqbiOSUHmh2Tn2zahI%3D&ved=0CF0Qyjc&ei=B8AoVJmOFYHN7QbhxoHABA#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=NZj8GQ9bvcZ6HM%253A%3BEYknVe4QNOjtJM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fimages.tradingpost.com.au%252FEHIKoQwk3HEAAAEaPFQg3xbA%252FD1105202392232%252Fd1105202392232_c-Resized320x240.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.tradingpost.com.au%252FCaravans%252FCaravans-%252FCARAVANS-FOR-SALE-SUNSHINE-COAST-FRANKLIN-PRINCETON-TANDEM-186%252FNambour%252FQLD%252FAdNumber%253DD1105202392232%3B320%3B240)

I'm only posting this as an answer because the address of that pic is too long for a comment. But I think the question is Off Topic.

Answer (score 0):

it's **KINGSTON** 6, the postal code of the area where she grew up which is Papine. University of Technology and University Hospital of the West Indies use the same code and the University of the West Indies Main Campus is around the corner in Kingston 7.

Never too late to share knowledge :D

Comment: This information is already given in the accepted answer.